# Multiple Constructors in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

When I try to write multiple constructors in coffee script, i get this error: `cannot define more than one constructor in a class`.

How can I do this:

```
class Vector2
  x: 0
  y: 0

  constructor:() ->

  constructor:(@x, @y) ->

  constructor:(vector) ->
     x = vector.x
     y = vector.y
```

I want to have an empty constructor and 2 other constructors. Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

simple do that in the coffeescript way:

```
class Vector
  constructor:(@x=0,@y=0) ->
      if typeof @x is "object"
        vector=@x
        @x=vector.x
        @y=vector.y

###
test start
###
v=new Vector()
console.log v.x,v.y
v=new Vector(1,1)
console.log v.x,v.y
v=new Vector {x:1,y:1}
console.log v.x,v.y
###
test end
###
```

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible. You could use the arguments object though. Just an example this could be better:

```
constructor:() ->
    switch arguments.length
        when 0 
            //no args
        when 1
            // vector
        when 2
            // coords
```

Here's the ticket asking for overloading functionality, no patch was submitted and Ashkenas closed it: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/531

Comment: `arguments` should be a parameter or thats just there?

Comment: `arguments` is a magic object, a pseudo array, in JavaScript that is available in functions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: For CoffeeScriptification :)
One could use `constructor:(args...) -> switch args.length ...`

Comment: I could see the usefulness of that if you were defining a few named variables before the splat but what advantages would it offer in this instance?

Comment: When closing the ticket Ashkenas mentioned that he would reopen the ticket if a patch is provided. So if you're feeling ambitious you could add the feature. Some of the proposed solutions in the ticket were pretty straightforward syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific about why this is not possible in JavaScript, and as such in CoffeeScript as well:
JavaScript does not allow overloading of methods, since methods **are just hash keys** of an object (be it `this`,a *prototype* of `this` -- or the *context stack* object if you are using a function expression). Therefore, methods are identifiable only by their name, not their entire signature (params passed or return value). Because of this, the same function allows you to read the actual passed params dynamically, using the `arguments` pseudo-array.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by JaredMcAteer, multiple constructors are not technically possible, but island205's suggestion achieves the same effect.

As another alternative, how about using class methods or plain functions with meaningful names over multiple constructors? Using your example, how about this?

```
class Vector2
  constructor:(@x, @y) ->

  @copy:(vector2) -> new Vector2(vector2.x, vector2.y)

  @zero:() -> new Vector2(0, 0)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
   a = new Vector2(1, 2)
=> Vector2 { x: 1, y: 2 }
   b = Vector2.zero()
=> Vector2 { x: 0, y: 0 }
   c = Vector2.copy(a)
=> Vector2 { x: 1, y: 2 }
```